# Double quotes need to be removed and insert statement order need to be fixed

Tags: postgresql, oracle, database-migration, ora2pg

I am using ora2pg to export `TABLE` and `INSERT` type from oracle database. [https://ora2pg.darold.net/documentation.html#:~:text=Ora2Pg%20consist%20of,QUERY%2C%20KETTLE%2C%20SYNONYM](https://ora2pg.darold.net/documentation.html#:%7E:text=Ora2Pg%20consist%20of,QUERY%2C%20KETTLE%2C%20SYNONYM).

I have 2 questions.

The TABLE and INSERT sql statements have double quotes for table and column names but I want to create them without double quotes. Is it possible to configure this in the `.conf` file?

The INSERT sql file that is generated by ora2pg does not have the sql statements in right order. The parent table data should be inserted first before trying to insert data into child table due to foreign key constraints. But the INSERT sql file generated by ora2pg is not taking this into account so this is causing error because the child table insert statement is present before the parent table. Is this how ora2pg works or am I doing something wrong in the `.conf` file?

Comment: Why do you care about double quotes? It's just a defensive tactic to ensure the SQL always works no matter the table/column names.

Comment: _"The child table data should be inserted first before trying to insert data into parent table due to foreign key constraints."_  Just the opposite.  You have to create the parent row first.  You can't have children without parents.

Comment: *The child table data should be inserted first before trying to insert data into parent table due to foreign key constraints* - this is wonky. In a normal rdbms the parent must exist before the child can. Perhaps just turn off all constraints then load the data, then back on at the end

Comment: @Bohemian: if the upper-case names from Oracle are quoted, that would make them upper case in Postgres as well (and case-sensitive). Not a very good thing to do.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name you're right; anyone who names tables/columns with any funky characters at all, especially spaces, deserves no mercy. I say `sed -i '' 's/"//g' export.sql` and let the chips fall where they may